# Is there a way to verify the existence of an email address without using telnet?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

If I want to verify if a particular email address exists, how do I do that without using telnet?

Comment: What’s wrong with telnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a program called "Advanced email verifier" I recall it from 10 years ago I suppose I used it once.
There's a free version, I don't know if it times out after x days.
http://www.glocksoft.com/email-verifier/aev-editions-business-personal-free/

Answer (score 1):

Try this website: http://verify-email.org

Answer (score 0):

Try emailing the address and see if it bounces back or not